# How to call stored procedures in Cosmos DB via Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Cosmos DB in a project via Entity Framework Core.
I want to run stored procedures through Entity Framework Core. I found a way how to do this through the Cosmos DB client, but I just can't find how to do it through Entity Framework Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and then:

```
public async Task RunStoreProcedureAsync()
{
    _context.Database.GetCosmosClient().GetContainer("databaseId", "containerId").Scripts
        .ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("procedureId", new PartitionKey("yourKey"), Array.Empty<dynamic>());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call it from the System.Data.Entity.DbContext class and you can use it like this in c#:

var userTypes= ((IObjectContextAdapter) this). ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable>("sp_procname", parameter1, parameter2);

You can check details [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: I don't use Entity Framework 6. I use Entity Framework Core